# Elixir: converting a struct to erlang for sys.config

Tags: struct, environment-variables, elixir

I am using a library called Tirexs to interact with elastic search, but the environment config for it only works with a %URI{} struct. In production all of the environment variables are loaded from sys.config, which is an Erlang data structure.

How would an Elixir struct be represented as and Erlang data structure?

Comment: See if this [Question and Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891758/elixir-how-to-convert-a-map-struct-to-a-record-struct) answers your question.

Comment: The code in the lib that loads the config pattern matches on a `%URI{}` struct. I haven't been able to get a working data structure for my understanding of that answer

Comment: Struct is defined here: https://github.com/Zatvobor/tirexs/blob/aa5943f92faf66cf316066453d470738c9c4a446/mix.exs (and probably other places in the same repo).  Google is your friend.

Comment: That's the problem I'm bumping up against. The lib uses structs instead of the easier to work with keyword list. Our deployment points to a unique elasticsearch address that gets loaded from `Application.get_env`, as shown here `https://github.com/Zatvobor/tirexs/blob/aa5943f92faf66cf316066453d470738c9c4a446/lib/tirexs.ex#17`. The env is in turn loaded from sys.config, an erlang data structure. The defaults that are loaded from the mix file you have linked won't work for our elastic search in production as it's located on a remote cluster, not the local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to see how a particular data structure would look like in Erlang is to print it.

```
:io.format("~tw~n", [my_struct])
```

Gives a canonical representation of any term in Erlang syntax. In that sense it's similar to Elixir's `inspect/2`.